# iOS - UIWebview - Scroll and hold stops JavaScript

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView displaying a page that contains a Javascript counter.

This page must be scrollable. However when I tap and scroll and then don't let go, the Javascript counter stops.

Undesirable to say the least as both scrolling and counting are imperative!

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved this was to get the client to change their Javascript code so the counter was based on a reference date so no matter how long the timer is stopped for, it will always be correct after a subsequent fire.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens with Mobile Safari. I don't think there's anything you can do here but run the important code on the view controller.